# Multiple comparison tests after using Robust method (lmrob)

Tags: robust

I have some violation of assumptions (normality and equality of variances) is my analysis and I decided to a use robust technique (**lmrob** function in R). I have a continuous response, one categorical predictor and one covariate. I was wondering which test I should use for the **multi-comparisons test/Post hoc analysis**?

Comment: Can you please share how to do the robust pairwise comparisons with Bonferroni correction in R?

Answer (score 1):

Almost all of the usual suspects (closed testing procedures,  Bonferroni-Holm, Bonferroni, graphical testing procedures, resampling based methods...) do not really depend on the analysis you performed,  as long as it produces a valid p-value.

Comment: thanks for the reply. It means that after running the robust method, I can use Tukey, Bonferroni as the Post Hoc tests? But I heard that the Tukey method is based on the normality assumption.

Comment: Tukey would be an example of a test that would not work. Those tests that just operate on p-values are the ones where there is no problem, similarly if resampling is the key ingredient.

Comment: @ Björn, can I use the robust pairwise comparisons with Bonferroni correction.

Comment: Bonferroni makes no assumptions about where the p-values come from, so if they are valid  p-values that is fine.